# how to access NSLayoutConstraint into tableviewcell with identifier to it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint, uitableview

I am using `autolayout` into my project and there is one situation in which I stuck. I already done with it Custom `XIB` of `TableviewCell` but I want to do it with default prototype cell of `Tableview`. My design is like below

[image: design]

Now In my design I select `constraint` top to button and giving identifier like below

[image: constraint]

In `Tableview` Prototype `cell`, I cant give outlet of it. So how can i access that `NSLayoutConstraint` with identifier. I search through web but nothing found

Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: Do you have custom cell class for your tableview?

Comment: No custom cell, Default prototype cell of tableview

Comment: Do you want to update your NSLayoutConstraint or change its value @ run time?

Comment: change value at runtime for diffrent conditions

Comment: Do you want single constrain to update? at run time

Comment: yes, Same constraint I want to update for diffrent conditions

Comment: if you have a custom class for uitableviewcell you can connect iboutlet for your constraint. y can't?

Comment: @AnshaD In question i already given detail, I have no custom cell

Comment: i didn't mean a separate xib for u r cell, i mean just a class subclassed from uitableviewcell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
    NSArray *constraints = [myView constraints]; // Here myView is a reference to the required UI component 
    int count = [constraints count];
    int index = 0;
    BOOL found = NO;

    while (!found && index < count) {
        NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = constraints[index];
        if ( [constraint.identifier isEqualToString:@"topconstraint"] ) {
            //save the reference to constraint
            constraint.constant = yourValue;
            found = YES;
        }
        index++;
    }
```

Using Predicate also, one can filter out:

`constraints.filter{ $0.identifier == "MyIdentifierText" }.first { }`

Comment: Please share also in swift. I will try it and let you know

Comment: If I make a loop into tableviewCell my response of tablview is slow and I dont want to do like that. And there are too many constraints into tableviewcell and It checks for every constraint So I think it takes a time to find it

Comment: @Jecky We can use predicate too.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you, Just trying it

Comment: Ok, Just got it with predicate. now I want to change that constraint value How can i change it ?

Comment: constraint.constant = yourValue

Comment: @DheerajD cant access value, It says property is immutable

Comment: @Mrunal your answer is correct but how can I assign new value to constraint, It says property is immutable

Comment: @DheerajD cant access value, It says property is immutable

Comment: @Jecky Please add your code in question, how you are accessing and how you are changing its value.

Comment: @Mrunal Its type casting issue, I just solved it. Thank you for your answer

Comment: ohh sure, Its my old issue